# MODX Revo: How can make pages load fast?

Tags: modx-revolution

I'm working on a site with modx revo. I'm really annoyed by the slow loading op pages. There's a 2sec wait for a page load om my localhost ánd I have a SSD. I've been looking around to find out how to make pageload faster.

I do have alot of getResources-/Gallery (9 total) calls and two Wayfinder calls. I've read it had to to with those, so I got rid of all the getResources and changed them to customs snippets that do only what I need them to do, build a 3-4 item menu. It's still slow, only few hunderd ms slower.

The Galleries (5) are only 3-4 images. I also use babel that checks every resource id for it's translation counterpart.

I'm wondering if it has anything to do with my wampserver (v 2.2) settings...

Now that I've summed it all up, I does look like a heavy page. Will I get long pageloads with any CMS this way?

Any help/hint/tips are apreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to "cache" all snippet tags **without** using the exclamation mark [[! ... ]].
 
Here is a blog about caching guidelines: http://www.markhamstra.com/modx-blog/2011/10/caching-guidelines-for-modx-revolution/ 
Here is a current discussion about speed performance: http://forums.modx.com/thread?thread=74902#dis-post-415390

Comment: This helped alot. Pages are loading faster now.

Comment: Jason has just posted [another tip](http://modx.com/blog/2012/09/14/tags-as-the-result-or-how-conditionals-are-like-mosquitoes/) regarding another issue between tags and conditional output.

Comment: I also found out that the Wayfinder plugin is playing a major part in slowing down the website. So caching that is essential.

Comment: Regarding to Wayfinder, it's needed to be uncached if you use usergroups for different resources.

Comment: The correct URL is: https://www.markhamstra.nl/modx/general/tips-tricks-tutorials/caching-guidelines-for-modx-revolution.html